# `sweep() function` in R taking `2L` as input

Tags: r, function

Very, very specific question, but I'm stuck trying to unravel the code within `contr.poly()` in R.

I am at what I think is the last hurdle... There is this internal function, `make.poly()`, which is the critical part of `contr.poly()`. Within `make.poly` I see that there is a `raw` matrix generated, which for `contr.poly(4)` is:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1 -1.5    1 -0.3
[2,]    1 -0.5   -1  0.9
[3,]    1  0.5   -1 -0.9
[4,]    1  1.5    1  0.3
```

From there the function `sweep()` is applied with the following call and result:

```
Z <- sweep(raw, 2L, apply(raw, 2L, function(x) sqrt(sum(x^2))), 
        "/", check.margin = FALSE)

     [,1]       [,2] [,3]       [,4]
[1,]  0.5 -0.6708204  0.5 -0.2236068
[2,]  0.5 -0.2236068 -0.5  0.6708204
[3,]  0.5  0.2236068 -0.5 -0.6708204
[4,]  0.5  0.6708204  0.5  0.2236068
```

I am familiar with the `apply` functions, and I guess `sweep` is similar, at least in syntax, but I don't understand what `2L` is doing, and I don't know if `"/"` and `check.margin = F` are important to understand the mathematical operation being performed.

EDIT: Quite easy... thanks to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jIUtTauL8tY) - it just normalizes vector lengths by dividing `"/"` by the `function(x)` applied column-wise, each entry of the matrix.

Comment: (1) `L` denotes an integer (not absolutely necessary, just someone being precise); (2) have you read `?sweep` .... ?

Comment: Sweep performs an operation on a matrix of size M X N using a vector of size N

Comment: if you've found the answer to your question, you should post it as an answer rather than editing your question to include the answer ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that answers the operation in the function `sweep()`.

I start with a matrix

```
> set.seed(0)
> (mat = matrix(rnorm(30, 5, 3), nrow= 10))
            [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
 [1,]  8.7888629 7.290780 4.327196
 [2,]  4.0212999 2.602972 6.132187
 [3,]  8.9893978 1.557029 5.400009
 [4,]  8.8172880 4.131615 7.412569
 [5,]  6.2439243 4.102355 4.828680
 [6,]  0.3801499 3.765468 6.510824
 [7,]  2.2142989 5.756670 8.257308
 [8,]  4.1158387 2.324237 2.927138
 [9,]  4.9826985 6.307050 1.146202
[10,] 12.2139602 1.287385 5.140179
```

and I want to **center** the data columnwise. Granted, I could use `scale(mat, center = T, scale = F)` and be done, but I find that this function give you a list of attributes at the end as such:

```
attr(,"scaled:center")
[1] 6.076772 3.912556 5.208229
```

corresponding to the column means. Good to have, but I just wanted the matrix, clean and neat. So it turns out that this can be achieved with:

```
> (centered = sweep(mat, 2, apply(mat,2, function(x) mean(x)),"-"))
            [,1]       [,2]        [,3]
 [1,]  2.7120910  3.3782243 -0.88103281
 [2,] -2.0554720 -1.3095838  0.92395779
 [3,]  2.9126259 -2.3555271  0.19177993
 [4,]  2.7405161  0.2190592  2.20433938
 [5,]  0.1671524  0.1897986 -0.37954947
 [6,] -5.6966220 -0.1470886  1.30259477
 [7,] -3.8624730  1.8441143  3.04907894
 [8,] -1.9609332 -1.5883194 -2.28109067
 [9,] -1.0940734  2.3944938 -4.06202721
[10,]  6.1371883 -2.6251713 -0.06805063
```

So the `sweep()` function is understood as:

`sweep(here goes matrix name to sweep through, tell me if you want to do it column (2) or row wise (1), but first let's calculate the second argument to use in the sweep - let's use apply on either the same matrix, or another matrix: just type the name here, again... column or row wise, now define a function(x) mean(x), almost done: now the actual operation in the function in quotes: "-" or "/"... and done`

Interestingly, we could have used the means of the columns of a completely different matrix to then sweep through the original matrix - presumably a more complex operation, more in line with the reason why this function was developed.

```
> aux.mat = matrix(rnorm(9), nrow = 3)
> aux.mat
           [,1]       [,2]      [,3]
[1,] -0.2793463 -0.4527840 -1.065591
[2,]  1.7579031 -0.8320433 -1.563782
[3,]  0.5607461 -1.1665705  1.156537

> (centered = sweep(mat, 2, apply(aux.mat,2, function(x) mean(x)),"-"))
            [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
 [1,]  8.1090952 8.107913 4.818142
 [2,]  3.3415323 3.420105 6.623132
 [3,]  8.3096302 2.374162 5.890954
 [4,]  8.1375203 4.948748 7.903514
 [5,]  5.5641567 4.919487 5.319625
 [6,] -0.2996178 4.582600 7.001769
 [7,]  1.5345313 6.573803 8.748253
 [8,]  3.4360710 3.141369 3.418084
 [9,]  4.3029308 7.124183 1.637147
[10,] 11.5341925 2.104517 5.631124
```